# Passing discount code in Orders API on Shopify

Tags: rest, post, shopify

I have been trying to develop an app that takes an order on Shopify on a different channel. I successfully placed an order through the API but I am not able to include the discount code along with the order. The JSON object for the POST data is as below:

```
{
  order: {
    email : request.params.order.email,    // string
    financial_status : 'pending',          // string
    send_receipt : true,                   // boolean 
    send_fulfillment_receipt : false,      // boolean
    note : request.params.order.note,      // string

    discount_codes : [], // supposed to be an array of Object| Problem here,

    line_items : request.params.order.line_items, // array
    customer : request.params.customer,    // JSON object 
    billing_address : request.params.order.billing_address,    // JSON object
    shipping_address : request.params.order.shipping_address   // JSON object
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, the **discount_codes** is like this -

```
Applicable discount codes that can be applied to the order. If no codes exist the value will default to blank. A Discount code will include the following fields: 

amount: The amount of the discount.
code: The discount code.
type: The type of discount. Can be one of : "percentage", "shipping", "fixed_amount" (default).
```

What am I doing wrong? My discount_codes is this

`[{amount: 100,code:'WELCOME10',type:'percentage'}]`

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: please provide also the actual discunt_code that is being sent (after the evaluation of the variables)

Comment: `[{amount: 100,code:'WELCOME10',type:'percentage'}]`

Answer (score 2):

According to this [response from Shopify](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/applying-discount-for-an-order-via-rest-api-285368) what you are trying to do is only possible if you pass the `total_discounts` field along as well with the total amount of the discount you want to apply.

As you will see in this other [answer](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/discount-code-usage-is-not-recorded-when-order-is-created-through-api-477304), any codes you have created through Shopify are not available to use with the API and their usage will not be recorded.

I was trying to use this API in order to test the application of different coupon codes that I was generating, but this does not seem to be possible. Apparently, the API was intended for applying discounts that are custom, not ones that already exist in Shopify. This is a frustrating limitation to me.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully create orders with discounts all the time, without ShopifyPlus as that is irrelevant. The data structure that works for me looks like this:

```
 [ { "code": "Shop By PizzleFuzzle 10%", amount: "10", "type": "percentage" } ]
```

Comment: Is the  amount "10" linked with "percentage" and not the actual discount in cart?

Comment: That is creating an order with a 10% off discount code.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, got sick. So yeah, the code didn't work for me. Just something wasn't  right I guess. Either way Shopify launched a new feature for me not use this custom payments all together. Thanks for the help @David Lazar..

Comment: What new feature do you speak of?

Comment: Rules based Cash on Delivery checkout option.

Comment: where is that documented?

Comment: It's very hush hush for some reason - https://help.shopify.com/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/cash-on-delivery

Answer (score -1):

The discount object is available only for Shopify Plus merchants.

Once you are a Shopify Plus merchant, you will be able to create discount codes like that:

```
POST /admin/discounts.json
{
  "discount": {
    "discount_type": "percentage",
    "value": "15.0",
    "code": "balderdash"
  }
}
```

Please see more detailed documentation in the discount object at Shopify API: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/discount

Comment: I understand that. But I'm doing a POST it on Orders.json right? And it is with an already existing discount code.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the value property name instead of amount property name.

e.g.

```
{value: 100,code:'WELCOME10',type:'percentage'}
```

and not

```
{amount: 100,code:'WELCOME10',type:'percentage'}
```